# Dificuldade em visualizar e na paginação

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, modal, paginação

Tenho um menu com a opção de visualizar os telefones cadastrados, apenas os números que foram cadastrado sem mostrar o resto dos dados, a intenção e que o usuário clica na opção de visualizar no menu e abre um modal nesse modal aparece os números cadastrados, mais ou menos uns 8 por página... O problema e que eu consigo abrir o modal e aparece apenas o primeiro número do banco de dados nesse modal e não aparece a paginação embaixo também...

Segue o código da pagina index.php:

```html
<?php 
    include_once("../conn/conexao.php");//faz a conexao com o banco de dados
     
    //verifica a página atual caso seja informada na URL, senão atribui como 1ª página 
    $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1; 
 
    //seleciona todos os itens da tabela 
    $cmd = "select * from tb_numeros"; 
    $produtos = mysqli_query($conexao, $cmd); 
 
    //conta o total de itens 
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($produtos); 
 
    //seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 2 itens 
    $registros = 8; 
 
    //calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima 
    $numPaginas = ceil($total/$registros); 
 
    //variavel para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual 
    $inicio = ($registros*$pagina)-$registros; 
 
    //seleciona os itens por página 
    $cmd = "select * from tb_numeros limit $inicio,$registros"; 
    $produtos = mysqli_query($conexao, $cmd); 
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($produtos); 
     
    //exibe os produtos selecionados 
    while ($produto = mysqli_fetch_array($produtos)) { 
        echo "<div class='modal fade' id='VisualizarT' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='modalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
  <div class='modal-content'>
  <div class='modal-header'>
  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>×</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>
  <h3 class='modal-title' id='lineModalLabel' align='center'>Telefones Cadastrados</h3>
   <div class='modal-body'>
    <div class='form-group'>
    <input type='text' name='numero' class='form-control' id='exampleInputPassword1' value=".$produto['numero']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly' >
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  ";
 }
     
    //exibe a paginação 
    for($i = 1; $i < $numPaginas + 1; $i++) { 
        echo "<a href='index.php?pagina=$i'>".$i."</a> "; 
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o `while()` que traz toda a coleção de dados do banco tenha que ficar dentro da `<div class="modal-body">`.

Ex.:

```
// Considerando que esse trecho está dentro da <div> referida...
while ($produto = mysqli_fetch_array($produtos))
{
    echo '<div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="numero" class="form-control" value="' . $produto['numero'] . '" style="text-align: center;" readonly="readonly"></div>';
}
```

A paginação também teria que ficar dentro dessa `<div>` pra ser exibida dentro do *modal*.

Comment: isso mesmo, só que tipo, eu clico na paginação e tem o botão 1,2,3... quando clico no 2 ou no 3 caso eu cadastre mais de 8 ele sai do modal... você sabe o erro?

Comment: ele fecha o modal, mais ai eu clico no modal de novo ele ta na segunda paginação

Comment: Uma das coisas que vai acontecer é que nos links da paginação você recarrega a página (`index.php?pagina=$i`), portanto o *modal* vai fechar mesmo. Agora, caso esteja fechando sem redirecionar pode ser algum problema relacionado ao seu *jQuery*.

Comment: como faço para fazer isso no modal sem ter que redirecionar para outra pagina

Comment: Você pode continuar redirecionando, mas quando a página recarregar com o novo índice, teria que abrir o *modal* automaticamente. Ou então você pode utilizar **AJAX**, porém vai ter que alterar quase tudo no seu código pra adequar a essa solução.